# Ormlite int based enums coming as varchar(max)

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Can anyone tell me how to correctly get ORMLite to store enums as integers? I know that this was not supported in 2012 but i found code for some unit tests that suggest it should work now but it doesn't. When we try the column gets created as a varchar(max) in ms sql. We currently use a wrapping property that is ignored to convert the enum value to int but then you can't use it for queries etc so it is less than ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `[Flags]` attribute to enums you want ServiceStack to treat as integers.

[From v4.0.54](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/release-notes.md#ormlite) you can also use the `[EnumAsInt]` attribute which will save the enum as an `int` in OrmLite but still serialize it as a string.

Comment: Thanks Mythz testing it now!

Comment: only worry i have is that since this enum is not really a flag enum it may cause confusion down the track later. I will use this method for now but seems like it is not the perfect solution

Comment: I have to agree with @Seer. A different solution should be find since not all enum are Flags as well: marking an enum as a Flag when is not collides with most of coding guidelines.

Comment: It should be added, that the `[EnumAsInt]` attribute has to be added to the enum and not to the property in the POCO.